# Batch file to connect postgres in windows

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, postgresql-9.4

Hello expert I am new in postgres and i have to delete data from table1 in single click from batch file. I don't have any idea how to connect database in postgres from batch file in windows.It will be better for me if  you will provied me whole script with example. My dbname-"test", dbuser-"postgres", password="pes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pipe the command in batch, something like this.

```
(
echo DELETE FROM table_name where something=somethig;
) | D:/pgsql/bin/psql -h somehost -p 5432 -U postgres -d test
```

I however suggest you first try and do a `select from` as a test, before initiating any `deletes` to ensure you do not delete something you did not want to

```
(
echo SELECT * FROM tablename;
) | D:/pgsql/bin/psql -h somehost -p 5432 -U postgres -d test
```